# Laravel :Target class [LoginController] does not exist."

Tags: laravel, controller

Even the controller is in the right folder an has the right name, when i test it in thunder client i get:

> {   "error": "Error en la aplicación
> (Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException):Target
> class [LoginController] does not exist." }

Here's my controller in app/http/Controllers/api

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Models\Usuario;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $usuario = Usuario::where('login', $request->login)->first();
        if (
            !$usuario ||
            !Hash::check($request->password, $usuario->password)
        ) {
            return response()->json(
                ['error' => 'Credenciales no válidas'],
                401
            );
        } else {
            $usuario->api_token = Str::random(60);
            $usuario->save();
            return response()->json(['token' => $usuario->api_token]);
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my route in the folder routes/api

```
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
```

i have tried changing the name, i changed the route to

```
Route::post('login', [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\LoginController::class, 'login']);
```

and then said

> {   "error": "Error en la aplicación
> (Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError):Cannot declare
> class LoginController, because the name is already in use" }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing your namespace :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
[...]
```